# Iterating over arrays of dictionaries within a for loop

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsdictionary

I have to construct array of dictionaries in following format.

> [   { @"value": @1,@"day":@2,@"hour":@1} , {@"value": @1,@"day":@1,@"hour":@1 }....]

Right now am constructing each dictionary in following manner.

```
 NSDictionary *dict =  @{@"value":@1, @"day":@2,@"hour":@1};
 NSDictionary *dict2 = @{@"value": @1,@"day":@1,@"hour":@1};
```

Then I am adding this to an array.

```
 NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict,dict2,nil];
```

This is fine for known values, but I need to change the values of 'day' and 'hour' within a for loop and create multiple dictionaries in my array.

Firstly am creating the 'day' as follows.

```
    NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
    component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Then for 'hour' I created the for loop for the desired ranges as below.

```
for (int i =start ; i <=end; i++) {

         NSDictionary *dict =  @{@"value": @1, @"day":@weekday, 
         @"hour":@i};

}
```

The step I am struggling with is to update the 'hour' and 'day' within the 
 for loop. Secondly I need to create multiple dictionaries in the loop 
 adding all the values to single dictionary is not required. Single dict 
 should be like

> { @"value": @1,@"day":@2,@"hour":@1}

Once the array of dictionaries is created I pass it to NSdata object for JsonNSData object. My final output looks like below

> [{"value":1,"day":0,"hour":0},{"value":1,"day":0,"hour":1},{"value":1,"day":0,"hour":2},{"value":1,"day":0,"hour":3},{"value":1,"day":0,"hour":4},{"value":1,"day":0,"hour":5}]

Comment: A simple for each loop doesn't work for you?

Comment: No for loop is not working in this instance

Comment: Actually your question is not clear. Problem is in updating the dictionary values of array or in calculating the weekday? Could you please post an example of expected result?

Comment: Include this in your question. And up to? I mean what is the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need an array of dictionary not just a dictionary. After updating the question it is clear now.

```
NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Then for 'hour' I created the for loop for the desired ranges as below.

**Here you need an array:**

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i =start ; i <=end; i++) {
    NSDictionary *dict =  @{@"value": @1, @"day":@(weekday), @"hour":@(i)};
    [array addObject:dict];
}
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Comment: Thanks, what you mentioned is correct way of doing it. But compiler is complaining @signs against 'weekday' and 'i' because they both are Numbers and dict is expecting an object. I tried building without '@' signs too but it won't accept it.  'Collection element of type 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') is not an Objective-C object'

Comment: Just put them in brackets like `@(weekday)` I just pasted your code.

Comment: You're right dictionary or array expect an object type so converting them into number will be okay and you're doing it right just a minor mistake while using a variable you will have to put the variable inside a small bracket `@(variable)` while value can be  convert directly by `@10`. `@10 is equal to [NSNumber numberWithInt:10]`.

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding what you are trying to do i believe it would be much nicer if you where to create a basic object containing the three properties you are trying to read & modify then create an array of the aforementioned objects.

```
@interface YourObjectName : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *someValue;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *day;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *hour
@end

@implementation YourObjectName
@end
```

Then you can simply iterate through an array of 'YourObjectName' and modify/check the values.

```
for (YourObjectName* yourObject in yourObjectNameArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", yourObject)
    NSLog(@"%@", yourObject.someValue)
    NSLog(@"%@", yourObject.day)
    NSLog(@"%@", yourObject.hour)
}
```

Alternatively you can iterate through your existing array, then iterate through the dictionary keys to get and modify the values.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, my final output should be a json  which should be in [{dict}, {dict2}...]